# JavaScript. Push and read from Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am trying to push values into a multidimensional array and read values out of it based on code that i've seen on other posts on this site. This is my array push code.

```
SelectedWindowGraphs.push([ContainerIDValue,elementID+"chkbox"]);
```

ContainerIDValue is an integer and elementID+"chkbox" is what i want to store at that position in the array. Here is what i saw when i debugged my code:

[image]

This is not what i want. At position 0, i want CUT17chkbox, CUT18chkbox, and CUT19chkbox. How do i fix my array so that i does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// initialize an array at that position in case it has not been defined yet
SelectedWindowGraphs[ContainerIDValue] = (SelectedWindowGraphs[ContainerIDValue] || 
[]); 
// push the value at the desired position
SelectedWindowGraphs[ContainerIDValue].push(elementID+"chkbox");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to push to a subarray:

```
 if(!SelectedWindowGraphs[ContainerIDValue])
   SelectedWindowGraphs[ContainerIDValue] = [];

 SelectedWindowGraphs[ContainerIDValue]
  .push(elementID+"chkbox");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add elements at certain position just doing:

```
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]

arr[2] = "three";

console.log(arr);//[ 1, 2, 'three', 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

In a multidimensional array:

```
var arr = [ 1, [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 7 ]

arr[1][2] = "four";

console.log(arr);//[ 1, [ 2, 3, 'four', 5, 6 ], 7 ]
```

When you perform push you are adding one or more elements at the end.

```
var arr = [1,2,3]

arr.push(4,5);//you are adding 4 and then 5

console.log(arr);//[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

In a multidimensional array:

```
var arr = [1,2,[3,4]]

arr[2].push(5,6);//position 2

console.log(arr);//[ 1, 2, [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ] ]
```

To insert an element in a specific position (and move right element **n** positions) you could use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice). In the following case, 2th and 3th position

```
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

arr.splice(2, 0, 999, 8888);

console.log(arr);//[ 1, 999, 8888, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

In a multidimensional array:

```
var arr = [ 1, 2, [3,4,5], 6, 7 ]

arr.splice(2, 0, [8,9,10]);

console.log(arr);//[ 1, 2, [ 8, 9, 10 ], [ 3, 4, 5 ], 6, 7 ]
```